# Unity5.2でスクリプトからのフォグ設定

Tags: c#, unity3d

スクリプトからRenderSettings.fog = trueでフォグの設定を行うと、
PC上ではフォグが表示されているのですが、androidの実機にインストールして
実行するとフォグが表示されません…Unity4.4では同様の手順でスクリプトから
フォグ設定を行うとPC上でも実機でもフォグが表示されています。
Unity5以降ではフォグをスクリプトから設定する際に何か必要な手順はあるのでしょうか？
また、Unity5以降でスクリプトからフォグの設定を行えた方はいますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Unityのバグのような気がします。

メニューの、Edit ＞ Project Settings ＞ Graphics でインスペクタの Fogの設定を「Automatic」から「Manual」に変更しただけで実機でも Fogが出るようになりました。

Fogタイプが Linearで良ければ「Linear」だけにチェックしておけばより確実な動作になりそうです。

[image: Fog設定]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
無事Fogを表示させることが出来ました。